# Can't get float:right to work on all elements properly

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-float

I am certainly no css guru, but I thought this would have been an easy one. Sadly, I can't get it to work. My code is:

```
<div class="form-group" style="float:right;">
     <p><asp:Button ID="Submit" Text="Login" Visible="true" Enabled="True" CssClass="btn btn-green btn-lg" OnCommand="Login" runat="server" /></p>
     <p><a href="/ForgotPW.aspx">Forgot your password?</a></p>
     <p><asp:Label ID="SuccessMessage" Text="Thank you! Your request was successfully sent." ForeColor="Green" Visible="False" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
</div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

As the red arrow indicates, I need it aligned to the right side of the div like the rest of the elements in there.

NOTES:

- the only css applied to "form-group" is margin-bottom: 15px;
- if I apply the float:right directly to the button, it works, but then the "Forgot your password?" link moves up beside and to the left of the button and nothing I do can get it to move below the button. So frustrating.

Comment: You need to supply the HTML without the ASP cause most of us don't use ASP and have no way to test with that. Along with usable CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `float: right;` on the button and then put `clear: both;` or `display: block;` on the link to force it onto the next line.

Comment: Beautiful! I knew it would be simple. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

use `text-align:right` for paragraph
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u3xocpsw/)

```css
input {
  width: 90%;
}
form {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
}
form > div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-group > p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p>Username</p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Password</p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>
      <button ID="Submit">Login</button>
    </p>
    <p><a href="/ForgotPW.aspx">Forgot your password?</a>
    </p>
    <p>Thank you! Your request was successfully sent.</p>
  </div>
</form>
```